# PHP Select dropdown Option value array

Tags: php, mysql, select, html-select, dropdown

I'm trying to make my select dropdown filter on results by row if that makes any sense!

Essentially I have a table and there's 5 rows in it, each with different date - each row has a dropdown with a list of users that are available to work on that date. I have all the users showing correctly and I have it where it filters a user that can't work that day - the only issue is that it only seems to do it for the first result.

So for example;

User A can't work 10/06/2019 & 11/06/2019 - User A won't show in the dropdown for row dated 10/06/2019, but will show in row dated 11/06/2019.

User B can work on all dates on the table so will show in all dropdowns.

I've tried modifying my array and my query, tried using a counter too but not getting anywhere!

```
     if ($available_date == $stk_date) {
       $query = "SELECT * FROM user_master WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT UM.id FROM user_master UM JOIN bookings B ON B.id_item = UM.id JOIN stocktakes S ON B.the_date = S.stk_date)";
         $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
         //$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
         if ($result) {
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
             echo "<option value=$row[first_name]>$row[first_name]  $row[last_name]</option>'";
           }
           }
     }
     else {
       $query = "SELECT * FROM user_master";
         $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
         //$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
         if ($result) {
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
             echo "<option value=$row[first_name]>$row[first_name]  $row[last_name]</option>'";
           }
           }
     }

      echo "</select></td>";
```

*For some reason my code isn't including my first echo, it's just the id name of the select which is supervisor_id_1

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

**Update:**

Removed update as it's a different question.

Comment: It is a bit naughty to change your question after it has been answered. The original question "Why are the first results not showing in the dropdown" has been answered. if you have another question then you shoudl ask a new question

Comment: Apologies Rigs, it's my fault for not explaining clearly. What I needed to explain was that it only seems to take into consideration the first result of the if statement, it doesn't continue running it to check against other users if that makes any sense. Your suggestion actually fixed something I had no idea I had an issue with! I'll keeps yours marked as answered and post elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both your IF and ELSE you have a

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

that is reading the first row from your resultset, but you are not using in your output. Just remove those 2 lines, see code below for annotations

```
if ($available_date == $stk_date) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user_master 
                WHERE id NOT IN (
                                SELECT UM.id 
                                FROM user_master UM 
                                JOIN bookings B ON B.id_item = UM.id 
                                JOIN stocktakes S ON B.the_date = S.stk_date)";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    // remove, its just throwing your first result away 
    //$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if ($result) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<option value=$row[first_name]>$row[first_name]  $row[last_name]</option>'";
        }
    }
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user_master";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    // remove, its just throwing your first result away 
    //$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if ($result) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<option value=$row[first_name]>$row[first_name]  $row[last_name]</option>'";
        }
    }
}

echo "</select></td>";
```

Comment: Hey Riggs, thanks for the suggestion although still not working - getting the same result hmm. User A only doesn't show for 10/6/2019 but is still showing for 11/6/2019.

Comment: Are you sure that you removed both of the incorrect lines?

Comment: Yup - removing those actually fixed something I didn't realise haha - it's bringing back my first result as intended. Also, it seems to be working now after removing that line, my testing must have been flawed! Just need to iron out a few query issues I think now. Thanks a lot for explaining the issue Riggs.

Comment: Actually, something still seems to be wrong from what I can see hmm - the suggestion you gave me has fixed one issue although now what I'm getting is this;

User A can't work 10/6/2019 so he doesn't show
User A can't work 11/6/2019 but now shows for all dates.

Another example;

User A can't work 10/6/2019
User B can't work 11/6/2019 but now User A shows for all dates again.

Comment: I you want me to try and work out whats wrong I think I will need to see your schema for these tables and also the test data you are using

Comment: Sure - what would be the best way to go about doing that Riggs? (I've kept this answered and will remove the update)

Comment: Ask another Question, I will follow on and have a go at answering. But agian will need some more information as per above. Maybe a SQLFiddle would be best

Comment: Sure will do that now

Answer (score 0):

You need quotation marks for the value tag:

```
value="$var"
```

All in all there are some quotes at the end of the echo.

Comment: Only if there are spaces in `$var`

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine two string or concatenate variable, without combine string its always return last echo value. For example : `$ex='A1';  $ex.='B1'; $ex.='C2';`

```
Result - A1B1C2
```

Your Question Answer is :

```
$string = "<td><select>";
if ($available_date == $stk_date) {
   $query = "SELECT * FROM user_master WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT UM.id FROM user_master UM JOIN bookings B ON B.id_item = UM.id JOIN stocktakes S ON B.the_date = S.stk_date)";
     $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
     if ($result) {
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
         $string.="<option value=".$row['first_name'].">".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."</option>'";
       }
     }
 }else{
   $query = "SELECT * FROM user_master";
     $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
     if ($result) {
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
         $string.="<option value=".$row['first_name'].">".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."</option>'";
       }
     }
 }
$string.="</select></td>";
```

Comment: removing the quotes around the assoc index inside a double quoted string is quite legal. So `echo "<option value=$row[first_name]>$row[first_name]  $row[last_name]</option>'";` is quite legal syntax. **Try It**